# Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: strings: , while compiling: SELECT id, string FROM strings WHERE id =?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I get this Error

---

```
07-16 20:58:27.299: E/AndroidRuntime(14005): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: strings: , while compiling: SELECT id, string FROM strings WHERE  id = ?
```

---

I hava StringDB class that has ID and String to store objects of this class into SQLite Database. Please Debug it and give a solution. Here is the code:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "StringDB";

public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // SQL statement to create StringDB table
    String CREATE_StringDB_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE StringDBs ( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +"string"+ "TEXT )";

    // create StringDBs table
    db.execSQL(CREATE_StringDB_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older StringDBs table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS StringDBs");

    // create fresh StringDBs table
    this.onCreate(db);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * CRUD operations (create "add", read "get", update, delete) StringDB + get all StringDBs + delete all StringDBs
 */

// StringDBs table name
private static final String TABLE_STRINGS = "strings";

// StringDBs Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_STRING= "string";

private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID,KEY_STRING};

public void addStringDB(StringDB string){

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_STRING, string.getString()); // get author

    // 3. insert
    db.insert(TABLE_STRINGS, // table
            null, //nullColumnHack
            values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values

    // 4. close
    db.close();
}

public StringDB getStringDB(int id){

    // 1. get reference to readable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // 2. build query
    Cursor cursor =
            db.query(TABLE_STRINGS, // a. table
            COLUMNS, // b. column names
            " id = ?", // c. selections
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
            null, // e. group by
            null, // f. having
            null, // g. order by
            null); // h. limit

    // 3. if we got results get the first one
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    // 4. build StringDB object
    StringDB res=new StringDB();
    res.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    res.setString(cursor.getString(1));


    return res;
}

// Get All StringDBs
public List<StringDB> getAllStringDBs() {
    List<StringDB> StringDBs = new LinkedList<StringDB>();

    // 1. build the query
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_STRINGS;

    // 2. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    // 3. go over each row, build StringDB and add it to list
    StringDB StringDB = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            StringDB = new StringDB();
            StringDB.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            StringDB.setString(cursor.getString(1));


            // Add StringDB to StringDBs
            StringDBs.add(StringDB);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.d("getAllStringDBs()", StringDBs.toString());

    // return StringDBs
    return StringDBs;
}

 // Updating single StringDB
public int updateStringDB(StringDB StringDB) {

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("strings", StringDB.getString()); // get author

    // 3. updating row
    int i = db.update(TABLE_STRINGS, //table
            values, // column/value
            KEY_ID+" = ?", // selections
            new String[] { String.valueOf(StringDB.getId()) }); //selection args

    // 4. close
    db.close();

    return i;

}

    // Deleting single StringDB
    public void deleteStringDB(StringDB StringDB) {

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. delete
        db.delete(TABLE_STRINGS,
                KEY_ID+" = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(StringDB.getId()) });

        // 3. close
        db.close();

        Log.d("deleteStringDB", StringDB.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: Changer you `TABLE_STRINGS = "strings";` to `TABLE_STRINGS = "StringsDBs"` That or create `private static final String TABLE_NAME = "strings";` and in onCreate, change `CREATE TABLE StringsDBs ...` to `CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ...` and where `TABLE_STRINGS` is, make that `TABLE_NAME`

Comment: doesn't work your solution

Comment: I edited my comment. I'll create and answer post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Under `private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "StringDB";` add

   ```
   private static final String TABLE_NAME = "strings";
   ```
2. Change `String CREATE_StringDB_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE StringDBs ( " +
           "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +"string"+ "TEXT )";`

   to

   ```
   String CREATE_StringDB_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id " +
       "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, string TEXT)";
   ```
3. Change under `onUpgrade` @ `db.execSQL`

   to

   ```
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
   ```
4. Change all references of  `TABLE_STRINGS` to `TABLE_NAME`

Comment: Thanks, I should mention , After doing this Must unistall app Completly, reinstall again!

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong table name. You are creating `StringDB` and asking for `strings`

Answer (score 0):

You call the table StringDBs  when you create it and strings later on.  Choose one name.

Comment: Look at your CREATE statements.  Notice the tablename.  Look at your later statements.  Notice the tablename.  Notice they aren't the same.  Choose 1 and change it.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall your app and install againa . this is due to that the latest table is not added to your to older one.
the problem is because some of device is upgrading your app, so the checkDataBase() returning true , so you are not calling copyDataBase(). So you are using previous database which dont have generalSettings table . To solve this try-

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
if(newVersion>oldVersion)
  copyDatabase();
}
```

and

```
public InstallDB(Context context, String name) {
    super(context, name, null, DB_VERSION); 
    // DB_VERSION is an int,update it every new build

    this.ctx = context;
    this.DBNAME = name;
    this.DBPATH = this.ctx.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getAbsolutePath();
    Log.e("Path 1", DBPATH);

}
```

Let me know if it works and if not ??